# Not as tedious as it looks

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Given the sequences:

1000, 11, 6, 3, 5, 4

1 000 000, 7, 5, 4

993, 25, 10, 3, 5, 4

1513, 32, 9, 4

What are the next hundred numbers in the sequence starting at 0?

What are the first 6 terms starting at 1, 234, 567, 890?

Comment: @f'' I was typing out an answer D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next number in the sequence is the number of letters in the previous number when written out in English (although "1,000,000" is "one million" — apparently you left out the "one" when counting).

Additionally, you seem to be using the convention of writing out "and" in the numbers when they are more than one hundred ("nine hundred and ninety-three" has 25 letters in it).

So starting from 0, you get a hundred instances of 4 afterwards.

Starting from 1,234,567,890 (one billion two hundred thirty-four million five hundred sixty-seven thousand eight hundred and ninety), you get 87, 11, 6, 3, 5, 4.